# grouping the similar items

Tags: android

I am getting the parsed response from webservice as below

```
<Table>
    <Restaurant_ID>2153</Restaurant_ID>
    <restaurant_name>Bhagini Palace</restaurant_name>
    <address>210, 1st Main, 'A' Cross, ESI Hospital Road, 2nd Stage, Domlur, Bangalore</address>
    <costoftwo>Approx Rs. 400 for two (without alcohol)</costoftwo>
    <rating>2.6</rating>
    <timings>11:30 AM to 4 PM, 6:30 PM to 11 PM</timings>
    <Phone>08040799999,+919731323333</Phone>
    <Location_ID>53</Location_ID>
    <Location_name>Domlur</Location_name>
    <city_ID>1</city_ID>
    <city_name>Bangalore</city_name>
    <Cuisine_ID>8</Cuisine_ID>
    <Cuisine_name>North Indian</Cuisine_name>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Restaurant_ID>2153</Restaurant_ID>
    <restaurant_name>Bhagini Palace</restaurant_name>
    <address>210, 1st Main, 'A' Cross, ESI Hospital Road, 2nd Stage, Domlur, Bangalore</address>
    <costoftwo>Approx Rs. 400 for two (without alcohol)</costoftwo>
    <rating>2.6</rating>
    <timings>11:30 AM to 4 PM, 6:30 PM to 11 PM</timings>
    <Phone>08040799999,+919731323333</Phone>
    <Location_ID>53</Location_ID>
    <Location_name>Domlur</Location_name>
    <city_ID>1</city_ID>
    <city_name>Bangalore</city_name>
    <Cuisine_ID>13</Cuisine_ID>
    <Cuisine_name>Chinese</Cuisine_name>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Restaurant_ID>2153</Restaurant_ID>
    <restaurant_name>Bhagini Palace</restaurant_name>
    <address>210, 1st Main, 'A' Cross, ESI Hospital Road, 2nd Stage, Domlur, Bangalore</address>
    <costoftwo>Approx Rs. 400 for two (without alcohol)</costoftwo>
    <rating>2.6</rating>
    <timings>11:30 AM to 4 PM, 6:30 PM to 11 PM</timings>
    <Phone>08040799999,+919731323333</Phone>
    <Location_ID>53</Location_ID>
    <Location_name>Domlur</Location_name>
    <city_ID>1</city_ID>
    <city_name>Bangalore</city_name>
    <Cuisine_ID>26</Cuisine_ID>
    <Cuisine_name>Andhra</Cuisine_name>
  </Table>
```

I am displaying restaurant_name and Cuisines in the listview using customadapter as

```
holder.txtvalue.setText(mlist.get(position)
                        .getRestaurant_name()
                        + "\n"
                        + mlist.get(position).getCuisine_name());
```

but when the restaurant id's are same i want to group the cuisines name and need to display in listview.

i have tried something like this

```
cuisines = mlist.get(position).getCuisine_name();

                Integer id = mlist.get(position).getRestaurant_ID();
                Log.d("restaurant_id", ""+id);
                for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

                    if (id.equals(mlist.get(position+i).getRestaurant_ID())) {

                        if(id.equals(mlist.get(position+(i+1)).getRestaurant_ID())){

                            cuisines = cuisines +","+ mlist.get(position+i).getCuisine_name()
                                    +","+ mlist.get(position+(i+1)).getCuisine_name();  
                        }else

                        cuisines = cuisines +","+ mlist.get(position+i).getCuisine_name();
                        Log.d("cuisiene_id", ""+cuisines);
                    }
                }
                holder.txtvalue.setText(mlist.get(position)
                        .getRestaurant_name() + "\n" + cuisines);
```

But i will get cuisines name in group as well as individuals.

How can i avoid displaying individual one's?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Use an expandable list view. Populate the groups views based on the restaurant id and the child view can be each item in the restaurant. Take a look at [the tutorials](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-expandablelistview-example.html) available out there to do this.

[image: expandable list view]